# making search addresses in flutter map (openstreet) but can't move the camera to marker location

Tags: flutter, widget, openstreetmap

so the question is simple.. why can't I move the map camera using mapcontroller when I put search criteria using geocoding or pletora? any way to do this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart';

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapsState createState() => _MapsState();
}

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  double long = 106.816666;
  double lat = -6.200000;
  double zoom = 15.0;
  double rotation = 0.0;
  LatLng point = LatLng(-6.200000, 106.816666);
  var location = [];
  MapController mapController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = MapController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            print(point);
            // ParseGeoPoint pts = await ParseGeoPoint(latitude: lat,longitude: long);
            // ParseObject data = await ParseObject('OrderIndividu')..set('AlamatG', pts);
            // await Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Save Alamat'),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Map'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            FlutterMap(
              mapController: mapController,
              options: MapOptions(
                onTap: (p) async {
                  location = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
                      new Coordinates(p.latitude, p.longitude));

                  setState(() {
                    long = p.longitude;
                    lat = p.latitude;
                    point = p;
                    print(p);
                    print(long);
                    print(lat);
                  });

                  print(
                      "${location.first.countryName} - ${location.first.featureName}");
                },
                center: LatLng(-6.200000, 106.816666),
                zoom: zoom,
              ),
              layers: [
                TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate:
                    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                MarkerLayerOptions(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      point: point,
                      builder: (ctx) => Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 34.0),

              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: TextField(
                      onSubmitted: (val) async{
                        final query = val;
                        var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
                        var first = addresses.first;
                        await mapController.moveAndRotate(LatLng(first.coordinates.latitude, first.coordinates.longitude), zoom, rotation);
                        setState(() {
                          long = first.coordinates.longitude;
                          lat = first.coordinates.latitude;
                          point = LatLng(first.coordinates.latitude, first.coordinates.longitude);
                        });
                        print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        hintText: "Cari Alamat Anda",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Center(
                  //   child: Card(
                  //     child: Padding(
                  //       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  //       child: Column(
                  //         children: [
                  //           Text("${location.first.featureName},${location.first.locality},${location.first.countryName}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
                  //         ],
                  //       ),
                  //     ),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

is there any coding for me to manipulate camera on the map to the marker location? I dont know any function to do this.. not even mapcontroller. so anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guess I found a way to search for mapping both from clicking and on textfield box. it was done using MapController.move(double LatLng, double zoom)

here is the code

```
body: Stack(
          children: [
            FlutterMap(
              mapController: mapController,
              options: MapOptions(
                controller: mapController,
                onTap: (p) async {
                  location = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
                      new Coordinates(p.latitude, p.longitude));
                  setState(() {
                    long = p.longitude;
                    lat = p.latitude;
                    point = p;
                    mapController.move(LatLng(p.latitude, p.longitude), zoom);
                  });

                  print(
                      "${location.first.countryName} - ${location.first.featureName}");
                },
                center: point,
                zoom: zoom,
              ),
              layers: [
                TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate:
                    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                MarkerLayerOptions(
                  markers: [
                    Marker(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      point: point,
                      builder: (ctx) => Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 34.0),

              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: TextField(
                      onSubmitted: (val) async{
                        final query = val;
                        var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
                        var first = addresses.first;
                        setState(() {
                          long = first.coordinates.longitude;
                          lat = first.coordinates.latitude;
                          point = LatLng(first.coordinates.latitude, first.coordinates.longitude);
                          mapController.move(LatLng(first.coordinates.latitude, first.coordinates.longitude), zoom);
                        });
                        print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        hintText: "Cari Alamat Anda",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Center(
                  //   child: Card(
                  //     child: Padding(
                  //       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  //       child: Column(
                  //         children: [
                  //           Text("${location.first.featureName},${location.first.locality},${location.first.countryName}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
                  //         ],
                  //       ),
                  //     ),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Comment: Which Geocoder do you use and does it need a Google Maps API key?

Comment: I found out which Geocoder you are using but despite it works, it says that it uses deprecated code that Flutter later is going to remove and not support anymore. Anyone have found any free alternative?